# How to filter and display Categories in react

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, filter

I am trying to filter through some data to display the results based on the category chosen. I believe I am approaching it correct. But I also don't think I am filtering my data correct. Can I be guided as to what approach to take to display only movies based on category chosen. My regular text input is filtering but I can seem to get my mind to understand what I am doing wrong using select. The categories are a nested array in a json file. See example...

```
{
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Crocodile Dundee",
      "year": "1986",
      "runtime": "97",
      "genres": ["Adventure", "Comedy"],
      "director": "Peter Faiman",
      "actors": "Paul Hogan, Linda Kozlowski, John Meillon, David Gulpilil",
      "plot": "An American reporter goes to the Australian outback to meet an eccentric crocodile poacher and invites him to New York City.",
      "posterUrl": "/images/crocodiledundee.jpg"
    }
```

My App js where I have the state and function to filter

```
function App() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState("");
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [genre, setGenre] = useState("");

  const searchMovie =  (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
    const newFilter = movies.filter((value)=>{
      return value.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
    });
    setMovies(newFilter); 
  }

  const changeCategory = (e) =>{


    const id = e.target.value;
    const result = movies.filter((currData)=>{
      const category = currData.genres.map(rating =>( rating.genre  ))

      return category == id

    });
    console.log( result)
    setGenre(result)

  }


  useEffect(() => {
    const loadMovieInfoInfo = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(" http://localhost:5000/movies");
        
        setMovies(response.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    loadMovieInfoInfo();
  }, []);
```

This is my component where I am trying to filter and render the data.

```
const MovieList = ({ movies, searchTerm, setSearchTerm, searchMovie, genre, changeCategory}) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="filterMain">
        <h3>Search or filter to find your favorite movie</h3>
        <form  onClick={searchMovie}>
          <select
            value={genre}
            onChange={changeCategory}
            name=""
            id="genreOptions"
          >
            <option value="comedy">Comedy</option>
            <option value="fantasy">Fantasy</option>
            <option value="crime">Crime</option>
            <option value="drama">Drama</option>
            <option value="music">Music</option>
            <option value="adventure">Adventure</option>
            <option value="history">History</option>
            <option value="thriller">Thriller</option>
            <option value="animation">Animation</option>
            <option value="family">Family</option>
            <option value="mystry">Mystry</option>
            <option value="biography">Biography</option>
            <option value="film-noir">Film-Noir</option>
            <option value="romance">Romance</option>
            <option value="scifi">Sci-Fi</option>
            <option value="war">War</option>
            <option value="western">Western</option>
            <option value="horror">Horror</option>
            <option value="musical">Musical</option>
            <option value="sport">Sport</option>
          </select>
          <></>
          <input
            type="text"
            name=""
            id="text"
            value={searchTerm}
            onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Search"
          />
          <button>Look for Movies</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className="main">
        {movies &&
          movies.slice(0,20).map((movie, index) => (
            <>
              <div key={index}>
                <div className="content">
                  <Link to={`/movielist/${movie.id}`}>
                    <img key={movie.id} src={`${movie.posterUrl}`} alt="" />
                  </Link>
                  <div className="innerContent">
                    <h1 id="movieTitle">
                      <span className="desc">Title: </span>
                      {movie.title}
                    </h1>
                    <h3 id="moviePlot">
                      <span className="desc">Year: </span>
                      {movie.year}
                    </h3>
                    <h3 id="moviePlot">
                      <span className="desc">Director: </span>
                      {movie.director}
                    </h3>
                    <h3 id="moviePlot">
                      {" "}
                      <span className="desc">Actors: </span>
                      {movie.actors}
                    </h3>
                    <h3 id="moviePlot">
                      <span className="desc">Plot: </span>
                      {movie.plot}
                    </h3>
                    <h3 id="moviePlot">
                      <span className="desc">Genre: </span>  
                      {movie.genres.map(rating =>(" / " +rating +" " ))}
                    </h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two goals that we will achieve here:

1. Select Movies by Genre
2. Search Movies

Ok, let's do it.

Spoiler: [Top 100 Greatest Movies of All Time app](https://oo3o1g.csb.app/)

### Setup

Please make sure you have two `.json` files which are **movies.json** & **genreOptions.json**.

```json
# ./movies.json
[
  {
    "title": "The Godfather",
    "year": "1972",
    "runtime": "175 min",
    "genre": ["Crime", "Drama"],
    "directors": "Francis Ford Coppola",
    "actors": ["Marlon Brando", "Al Pacino", "James Caan", "Diane Keaton"],
    "plot": "The aging patriarch of an organized crime dynasty in postwar New York City transfers control of his clandestine empire to his reluctant youngest son.",
    "posterUrl": "/M/MV5BM2MyNjYxNmUtYTAwNi00MTYxLWJmNWYtYzZlODY3ZTk3OTFlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_UY209_CR3,0,140,209_AL_.jpg"
  },
 ...
]
```

```
# ./genreOptions.json
[
  {
    "value": "",
    "label": "All Genre"
  },
  {
    "value": "action",
    "label": "Action"
  },
  {
    "value": "adventure",
    "label": "Adventure"
  },
 ...
]
```

and import those json data into our component:

```js
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import allMovies from "./movies.json";
import genreOptions from "./genreOptions.json";
```

### Select Movies by Genre

Here, we will create a select option based on genre values inside our **genreOption.json** file. First create **genre** state that would become our selected genre placeholder.

```
export default function App() {
  const [genre, setGenre] = useState("");
  ...
}
```

Next, we create our select options tag element. At `select` DOM tag, we pass **genre** state into the **value** attribute and at **onChage** event handler we pass an arrow function that will update the **genre** state by using genre setter  (**setGenre**) when an **onchange** event occurs. Here, the arrow function will run once the selected option changes.
We render the *option* tag by iterating the **genreOptions** and passing genreOption value and label to it.

```
  return (
    <select
      value={genre}
      onChange={(e) => setGenre(e.target.value)}
    >
      {genreOptions.map((option, i) => {
        return (
          <option value={option.value} key={i}>
            {option.label}
          </option>
        );
      })}
    </select>
  )
```

Next, we create a memoized **movies** constant, that depends on the **genre** value. When **genre** changes, the **allMovies** filtering process will be re-run again resulting in an updated filtered movies array that based on the **selected** genre.

```js
  const movies = useMemo(() => {
    return allMovies.filter((movie) => {
      // return all movies when options All genre selected (genre value is "")
      if (genre === "") {
        return allMovies;
      }
      // if not an empty string, create an array of lowering case genre
      const movieGenre = movie.genre.map((val) => val.toLowerCase());
      // return movie if the genre is included in movieGenre
      return movieGenre.includes(genre);
    });
  }, [genre]);
```

At the moment, we render the movie details without styling to see whether the **select options** event management has run as expected. Open your browser and check your select options. It should working if you follow the steps correctly.

```js
  ...
  return (
    <select>
      ..
    </select>
    <div>
      {movies.map((movie, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <h1>{movie.title}</h1>
            Year:
            <span>{movie.year}</span>
            Runtime:
            <span>{movie.runtime}</span>
            Genre:
            <span>{movie.genre.join(", ")}</span>
            Director:
            <span>{movie.directors}</span>
            Actors:
            <span>{movie.actors.join(", ")}</span>
            <p>{movie.plot}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

### Search Movies

Now it is time to create our **Search Input** where we can search the movie by typing keywords in our search input. We use **searchTerm** state to keep our keywords query. Pass **searchTerm** state to input value attribute and pass **setSearchTerm** setter into input's **onChange** handler. By doing this the onChange handler will call the **setSearchTerm** on every keystroke and the searchTerm value will have an updated value as the user types.

```js
function App() {
  const [genre, setGenre] = useState("");
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTem] = useState("");
  ...

  return (
    <div>
      <select>
        ..
      </select>
      <input
        name="searchMovie"
        placeholder="Search Movie"
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={(e) => setSearchTem(e.target.value)}
      />
      <div>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Then we add this **useEffect** block. The code in this block will re-run once the **searchTerm** value changes. It happen when the user types the search keywords in the input element. Here, setter **setGenre("")** will be called only when the searchTerm is not empty. This will reset our select option and *All Genre* will be the selected option.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerm !== "") {
      setGenre("");
    }
  }, [searchTerm]);
```

Next, update your **memoized movies** function. Add `searchTerm deps` and the `else block` where we define **searchFields** that becomes filter reference. This function will return **allMovies** when the **searchTerm** value is an empty string and [shallow copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Shallow_copy) of **allMovies** contains movies that pass the implemented test.

```js
const movies = useMemo(() => {
    if (genre === "") {
      if (searchTerm === "") {
        return allMovies;
      } else {
        // search input filter will return new array filled with movie that pass the test
        return allMovies.filter((movie) => {
          // define a string by combining all fields that will become search reference
          const searchFields =
            `${movie.title.toLowerCase()} ` +
            `${movie.year} ` +
            `${movie.directors.toLowerCase()}` +
            `${movie.actors.join("").toLowerCase()}` +
            `${movie.plot.toLowerCase()}`;
          // implemented test
          return searchFields.includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
        });
      }
    }
    // select option filter
    return allMovies.filter((movie) => {
      const movieGenre = movie.genre.map((val) => val.toLowerCase());
      return movieGenre.includes(genre);
    });
  }, [genre, searchTerm]);
```

Now, open your browser and type in the search input. The rendered movies should display the movies that contain the typed keyword.

Finally we add [tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/) styling and add **image** to our card. Here is the complete code.

[image: Edit objective-mirzakhani-oo3o1g]

```js
import { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react";
import allMovies from "./movies.json";
import genreOptions from "./genreOptions.json";

export default function App() {
  const [genre, setGenre] = useState("");
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTem] = useState("");

  const movies = useMemo(() => {
    if (genre === "") {
      if (searchTerm === "") {
        return allMovies;
      } else {
        return allMovies.filter((movie) => {
          const searchFields =
            `${movie.title.toLowerCase()} ` +
            `${movie.year} ` +
            `${movie.directors.toLowerCase()}` +
            `${movie.actors.join("").toLowerCase()}` +
            `${movie.plot.toLowerCase()}`;
          return searchFields.includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
        });
      }
    }
    return allMovies.filter((movie) => {
      const movieGenre = movie.genre.map((val) => val.toLowerCase());
      return movieGenre.includes(genre);
    });
  }, [genre, searchTerm]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerm !== "") {
      setGenre("");
    }
  }, [searchTerm]);

  return (
    <div className="p-6">
      <h1 className="text-xl font-bold my-6">
        Top 100 Greatest Movies of All Time
      </h1>
      <form className="flex flex-col w-72">
        <select
          className="px-2 py-1 border w-40"
          value={genre}
          onChange={(e) => setGenre(e.target.value)}
        >
          {genreOptions.map((option, i) => {
            return (
              <option className="py-2" value={option.value} key={i}>
                {option.label}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>
        <input
          className="border p-1 px-3 my-3"
          name="searchMovie"
          placeholder="Search Movie"
          value={searchTerm}
          onChange={(e) => setSearchTem(e.target.value)}
        />
      </form>
      <hr className="mb-6 mt-3" />
      <div className="lg:grid lg:grid-cols-2 lg:gap-4">
        {movies.map((movie, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={index}
              className="md:flex border rounded p-4 my-4 lg:my-0 text-ellipsis overflow-hidden"
            >
              <div className="flex-none md:w-48 flex justify-center items-center">
                <img
                  src={`https://m.media-amazon.com/images${movie.posterUrl}`}
                  alt=""
                />
              </div>
              <div className="lg:grow flex flex-col">
                <h1 className="text-base font-bold mt-2">{movie.title}</h1>
                <span className="text-sm mt-2">
                  Year:
                  <span className="m-2">{movie.year}</span>
                  Runtime:
                  <span className="m-2">{movie.runtime}</span>
                </span>
                <span className="text-sm mt-2">
                  Genre:
                  <span className="m-2">{movie.genre.join(", ")}</span>
                </span>
                <span className="text-sm mt-2">
                  Director:
                  <span className="m-2">{movie.directors}</span>
                </span>
                <span className="text-sm mt-2">
                  Actors:
                  <span className="m-2">{movie.actors.join(", ")}</span>
                </span>
                <p className="text-sm mt-2">{movie.plot}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your genre in `changeCategory` function to a filtered array of movies. You should set your genre directly to option's value which is `e.target.value`.

Other than that you are not setting your `movies` to genre filtered array, so you would not be displaying filtered movies. Also, you can use `includes` method to filter your movies with genre (Capitalizing your options' values are necessary to match the element in genre array).

```
const changeCategory = (e) => {
  setGenre(e.target.value)

  const filteredMovies = movies.filter((movie) => movie.genres.includes(e.target.value))
  setMovies(filteredMovies)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate it. I am not getting any movies to returned to render but this is still some progress. Been staring at this all day. Guess I just have to drill into the json object a bit more. Thanks

Comment: The reason movies are not getting rendered might be filteredMovies being an empty array, although it shouldn't be with the right adjustments. You can console.log it and check it out. Glad if i could help.